# Unable to download S3 objects larger then 100MB with Go SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I have a REST API with 2 endpoints: 1 handles the POST request to upload to S3 and the other serves files for the GET request which downloads the file from the bucket and serves it to the client. Now:

1. I am getting an access denied response when I try to download the file from S3 after 24 hours of upload although I was able to retrieve the file on the same day. Is there something that needs to be configured to prevent this? Does it relate to something like this https://medium.com/driven-by-code/on-the-importance-of-correct-headers-and-metadata-in-s3-origins-for-aws-cloudfront-50da2f9370ae?
2. when the download is initiated to get the file from S3, I get a time out error after 30 sec. The server is configure with a WriteTimeout of 15 minutes. How can one prevent this timeout? Note: This is not a lambda function or any type of serverless function. I am not using CloudFront either (not at my knowledge). Here is a snippet code for the GET request.

```
buf := aws.NewWriteAtBuffer([]byte{})
 s3Svc := s3.New(s)
 downloader := s3manager.NewDownloaderWithClient(s3Svc, func(d *s3manager.Downloader) {
     d.PartSize = 64 * MB
     d.Concurrency = 3
 })
 result, err := downloader.Download(
     buf, &s3.GetObjectInput{
         Bucket: aws.String(rc.AWS.Bucket),
         Key:    aws.String(fileName),
     })
 if err != nil {
     return nil, err
 }
d := bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes())
w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "filename="OriginalFileName)
http.ServeContent(w, r, filename, time.Now(), d)
```